# Google Play Services Missing in Extras folder in SDK Manager

Tags: android, google-play-services

I want to use google map in my app. I want to install Google Play Services in SDK Manager but when i go to SDK Manager, i find just Android Support Library and Intel x86 Emulator Accelator ( HAXM installer ),i don't see Google Play Services! Why? HOw can i install this?

Answer (score 0):

The Google play services are in the SDK Manager at the bottom under the category "Extra".

Comment: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-WOKvMY4Eq18/UZu_rgWoBgI/AAAAAAAACaQ/zzmtZWA0z44/s1600/Screen+Shot+2013-05-21+at+7.33.05+PM.png
It should be there, all SDK managers should have it

Comment: it's not there , i have just Android Support Library and Intel x86 Emulator Accelator ( HAXM installer ).

Comment: What version do u have? My current version is 23.0.2. If it is an old version I suggest updating it. Else try downloading and reinstalling a new version from the android webpage

Answer (score -1):

First install the packages which you need from the existing list. Then restart the SDK manager. When you do this you may get Google Play services under extras folder.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: But it helped me. i was also stucked in that situation. And found it somewhere, and it worked